# Would it possible to implement a button to the approach I'm taking to display information in a Google Maps marker in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm creating a small app that will help a user find a sports club. I'm currently creating a club coordinate variable in the MapsActivity.java file like so:

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

     mMap = googleMap;

     LatLng lansdowneRFC = new LatLng(53.3334103,-6.2201649);

    // Adds location to the map (includes a small bit of info about the club) 
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lansdowneRFC).title("Lansdowne RFC").snippet("Aviva Stadium, 62 Lansdowne Rd,"));
}
```

This produces the following result

[image: Screenshot of what the above code produces]

I'm trying to add a button to the information box that will bring the user to another activity (The activity will be a sign up form so they can join the club). Considering the approach I'm using is it possible to implement a button or will I have to approach it in another way? I've seen ideas like a custom popup window be suggested for this type of thing but how I implement that into a google maps marker instead of a button is where I'm hitting a brick wall. Any suggestions

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#custom_info_windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your own implementation of `InfoWindowAdapter` to your `GoogleMap` object with a call to `setInfoWindowAdapter()`.

And in the adapter you can override `getInfoContents()` to return whatever view you want.

But the down side is the view that is shown is not a live view, it's an image of the view you created, and you can handle the click on it using a `OnInfoWindowClickListener` that you set on the GoogleMap object with `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()`.

**But that handles the click on the whole window, not just the button.**

Another option is to know where your marker is at the screen and show a popup manually above it that has nothing to do with the map, but I would not recommend that approach, with Android's different device sizes and all, that could quickly get very ugly.